# Conversion between decimal data types loses precision with no error

Tags: sql-server

Why conversion between `decimal(5,5)` and `decimal(5,0)` doesn't produce an error?

```
create table #t1
(
    Number1 decimal(5,5),
    Number2 decimal(5,0)
);

insert into #t1
values (0.223, 5.0)

select (Number1 + Number2) as n
from #t1;
```

> [For decimal and numeric data types, SQL Server considers each
> combination of precision and scale as a different data type. For
> example, decimal(5,5) and decimal(5,0) are considered different data
> types.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Next

> [If the conversion isn't a supported implicit conversion, an error is
> returned.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[And according to this illustration conversion between two decimal is not implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#implicit-and-explicit-conversion)

Comment: Implicit conversion _supported_ <> no precision loss without error when relying on implicit conversion. The chart you reference (last link) explicitly says for decimal to decimal that it "Requires **explicit** cast to **prevent the loss of precision or scale**." (Emphasis mine.) Also Consider: `DECLARE @x varchar(3) = 'bob', @y varchar(1); SET @y = @x; SELECT @y;` If you want a specific outcome, use the same types or use explicit cast to the precision/scale you're after. The rules for what you might get if you leave it up to SQL Server are, well, complicated.

Comment: `isn't a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned.` does not apply to decimal -> decimal in that chart, since the chart does _not_ say that implicit cast between decimal and decimal is unsupported (e.g. with a red X). It would apply to other implicit conversions that _are_ unsupported (look for a red X on the chart), e.g. where date and time meet: `DECLARE @x date = getdate(), @y time; SET @y = @x;` yields `Msg 206, Operand type clash: date is incompatible with time`.

Comment: `decimal(5,5)` is a bit odd anyways - five digits total, all of which are *after* the decimal point? Is that *really* what you wanted? This means you can only store fractional values between 0.00000 and 0.99999 in that variable ...... (since there are no digits available before the decimal point......)

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you consider decimal(5,5) and decimal(5,0) to be different types, the result of applying an arithmetic operator to them is explicitly defined, and so isn't an implicit conversion.

> The following table defines how the precision and scale of the result
> are calculated when the result of an operation is of type decimal. The
> result is decimal when either:
>
> - Both expressions are decimal.
> - One expression is decimal and the other is a data type with a lower precedence than decimal.

[image]

[Precision, scale, and length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks)